# Storing GPS values for global use in app

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm writting the GPS application using javascript and phonegap. I'm going to implement such idea: 
1) I've created some global js variables like currentSpeed, longitude, latitude etc
2) Each time the watchPosition's onSuccess callback is fired, these variables are refreshed (new values from callback's 'position' parameter)
3) Then, wherever and whenver I can use these global values in my app.

Does this solution make sense or you would suggest another concept?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage)

It is a new feature in **HTML5**

```
// Setter
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

// Getter
localStorage.getItem("key"); // value

// Remove
localStorage.removeItem("key");
```

Comment: Thanks. Accually I'm using LS in my app, but I'm not sure if changing localStorage properties every second (I need such frequency) is the best solution in terms of performance. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I'm more of a fan of encapsulating the variables with some accessor methods (getters and setters)

Imagine that some time along the line you decide that you need to adjust a value in your lattitude by +2. Instead of having to change every single access to the global variable you can simply just alter the way your getLattitute() method returns so:

```
function getLattitude() {
    return _lattitude + 2;
}
```

Also make sure you pass parameters within an array instead of directly since it will be easier in the future to add another parameter to the array.

Comment: Acctually you're right ;) I'm going to refactor this in nearest future. Thanks ;)